# Preencher nova coluna (str) no Pandas DataFrame a partir de dados de outras colunas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estou trabalhando com uma base de dados de municípios brasileiros. Dentre as informações que ela possui, estão o nome do município, estado, se é capital, população, etc. Gostaria de trabalhar com os dados reunidos por região do país, incluídos em uma nova coluna.
Carreguei o dataset, fiz os ajustes e tal.
Criei as variáveis das regiões:

```
Norte = ['AM', 'PA', 'RR', 'AC','RO','AP', 'TO'],
Sul = ['PR', 'SC', 'RS'],
CentroOeste = ['MT', 'MS', 'GO', 'DF'],
Nordeste = ['BA', 'CE','MA', 'PB', 'PE', 'RN', 'SE', 'AL', 'PI'],
Sudeste = ['SP', 'RJ', 'MG','ES']
```

A seguir, criei o campo REGIAO, logo depois de Município e Estado:

```
df500.insert(2, 'REGIAO', 'NaN')
```

Para preencher a nova coluna usei:

```
df['REGIAO'] = df['ESTADO'].apply(lambda x: 'Sul' if x in Sul else 'Norte' if x in Norte else 'Nordeste' if x in Nordeste else 'Sudeste' if x in Sudeste else 'Centro-Oeste')
```

Entrentanto, a saída que recebo é a seguinte:

| Index | CIDADE | ESTADO | REGIAO | CAPITAL | POPULACAO_TOTAL_2010 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Brejo De Areia | MA | Centro-Oeste | 0 | 5577.0 |
| 1 | Cujubim | RO | Centro-Oeste | 0 | 15854.0 |
| 2 | Balbinos | SP | Sudeste | 0 | 3702.0 |
| 3 | Pacaraima | RR | Centro-Oeste | 0 | 10433.0 |
| 4 | Araquari | SC | Centro-Oeste | 0 | 24810.0 |
| 5 | Pedra Branca Do Amapari | AP | Centro-Oeste | 0 | 10772.0 |
| 6 | Ipiranga Do Norte | MT | Centro-Oeste | 0 | 5123.0 |
| 7 | Parari | PB | Centro-Oeste | 0 | 1256.0 |
| 8 | Colniza | MT | Centro-Oeste | 0 | 26381.0 |
| 9 | Luís Eduardo Magalhães | BA | Centro-Oeste | 0 | 60105.0 |

ou seja, só as entradas do sudeste e as do centro-oeste estão corretas, as demais aparecem sempre como centro-oeste. Tentei fazer de dois em dois, alterando a ordem das entradas,da sintaxe do else if, não consegui sair do lugar.
Alguém pode me ajudar?
Desde já agradeço

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente o problema esta sendo causado pela `,` que você esta colocando no final da lista Ex.:

```py
Norte = ['AM', 'PA', 'RR', 'AC','RO','AP', 'TO'],  # <
```

quando você faz um `print` dessa variável você pode notar que por causa dessa virgula a variável não é uma [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks) ela é uma [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) com uma [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks) dentro

```py
print( Norte )
# output: (['AM', 'PA', 'RR', 'AC', 'RO', 'AP', 'TO'],)
```

<sup>[veja funcionando online no ideone](https://ideone.com/IDwr6l)</sup>

então a solução é simples, remova as virgulas no fim dessas listas.

---

O seu `lambda` esta correto, eu achei ele um pouco complexo uma outra possibilidade seria utiliza o [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) como [`.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) para verificar e alterar esses valores como mostrado abaixo porém essa solução provavelmente será mais lenta.

```py
regiao = {
    "Norte":['AM', 'PA', 'RR', 'AC','RO','AP', 'TO'],
    "Sul":['PR', 'SC', 'RS'],
    "Centro Oeste":['MT', 'MS', 'GO', 'DF'],
    "Nordeste":['BA', 'CE','MA', 'PB', 'PE', 'RN', 'SE', 'AL', 'PI'],
    "Sudeste":['SP', 'RJ', 'MG','ES'],
}
 
for k in regiao:
    df.loc[ df['ESTADO'].isin(regiao[k]), 'REGIAO'] = k
```

<sup>[veja funcionando online no ideone](https://ideone.com/XcWyMc)</sup>

Comment: duas horas tentando de mil formas, e era só tirar a vírgula... agradeço o apontamento e agradeço também a alternativa apresentada!

Comment: Ola @annacoloda, que bom que pude ajudar  - Só para informar você pode votar em todas as respostas que achar útil, porem apenas uma resposta pode ser marcada como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅", fique a vontade para escolher a resposta que for mas apropriada. - Também vale dar uma passada em nosso [Tour]. 

Answer (score 1):

Tratar dataframes é muito mais rápido e seguro fazendo utilização de aplicações para dataframe. Sugiro não utilizar os if e else, tente fazer um merge, criando uma base onde já conste os estados e suas regiões

Eu montei aqui rapidamente um excel pela correria com os dados e fiz através o merge um teste. Funcionou perfeitamente, tente adaptar a sua necessidade.

outra sugestão é que trabalhando com o merge não há necessidade de você criar a coluna região, ao fazer o merge com a base através a coluna estado, o próprio python vai lhe trazer esta coluna. Veja a documentação para lhe atender.

[Documentação pandas \ merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
est_reg = pd.read_excel('estadosregiao.xlsx')


obj = {'ESTADO': ['MA', 'RR', 'AC', 'CE','MA', 'PB', 'PR', 'SP', 'GO', 'DF']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=obj)


final = pd.merge(df, est_reg, how='inner', on='ESTADO', suffixes=(False, False))

print(final)
```

resultado:

```
  ESTADO       REGIAO
0     MA     Nordeste
1     MA     Nordeste
2     RR        Norte
3     AC        Norte
4     CE     Nordeste
5     PB     Nordeste
6     PR          Sul
7     SP      Sudeste
8     GO  CentroOeste
9     DF  CentroOeste
```

Comment: estou começando agora, não conhecia o merge. vou pesquisar mais!
gracias!